# How to show grub menu after grub update?

Tags: grub2

I have 11.10 and Windows 7 in dual boot. Today I tried to update grub and I run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l    
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt 
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo grub-install
```

After installation and reboot, it does not show the grub menu (from which I can choose which OS to boot) and it directly boots Ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: Try holding Shift while booting to get to GRUB.

Comment: i try but nothing happen. which way i can add or recover windows7 loader in  boot loader

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu via wubi?

Comment: no live cd...and before update grub its workig well... and it was also show the grubloader also but now it cann't show grubloader and so i cannot load windows7.. if u cann't understand my problem than i can explain in other way.. because i m not good enough in explain. so plz reply and thank u..

Comment: I can understand your problem. I just don't see a way out right now.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to your live cd.

Then: in a terminal type.........

sudo mount /dev/sdXY

Example:

> sudo mount /dev/sda1

Run the grub-install command as described below. This will reinstall the GRUB 2 files on the mounted partition to the proper location and to the MBR of the designated device.

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX

Example:

> sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

Refresh the GRUB 2 menu with

> sudo update-grub.

reboot

**If this does not work for you - try the link bellow.**

https://launchpad.net/boot-repair